# Editing MSP432 .cmd file to declare variables accessible from inline ASM

Tags: c, assembly, mutex, msp432

I need to set up a mutex in my TI MSP432 C project, developed in CCS IDE. I'm not using an OS, but I have several ISRs competing for a buffer resource.

To obtain atomicity I want to go for assembly instructions, however I find it difficult to declare the variable so that it can be accessed from within the __asm block.

Should I use #pragma directives or edit the .cmd?
Could anybody post a complete example of a similar variable declaration case?

Thanks

Comment: Does your C compiler not provide pthreads mutexes?  Or [C11 `stdatomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic)?

Comment: Good point! I'll take a look at stdatomic